# @ApiModelProperty is set to model, but no fields are shown in the Swagger dock

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have a model, that has two fields, but none of is shown in the Swagger dock. What else should be done to make them being shown?

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.UUID;

@ApiModel(description = "Краткое описание сервиса для его выбора в dropdown")
public class DictServiceGroupView {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Название сервиса")
    String name;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Идентификатор сервиса")
    UUID id;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It needed setters and getters to be set on the class (don't know what actually of them). On my case they were introduced with `Lombok` annotations and fields appeared in the `Swagger` doc.

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.UUID;

@ApiModel(description = "Краткое описание сервиса для его выбора в dropdown")
@Getter //HERE
@Setter //HERE
public class DictServiceGroupView {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Название сервиса")
    String name;
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Идентификатор сервиса")
    UUID id;
}
```

[image]